# FlotJS wont plot data on the correct date

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

http://jsfiddle.net/jJNmV/

Yes I've multiplied my times by 1,000, and as you can see the dots do not appear on the date but rather a little bit to the side of it. Why does this happen?

My data and x-axis looks like:

```
{data: [[1351483200000, 12],[1351569600000, 1]], label: "Clicks"}, {data: [[1351483200000, 24],[1351569600000, 1]], label: "Opens"}
  ], {
    xaxis: {
      mode: 'time',
      timeformat: '%y/%m/%d',
      minTickSize: [1, 'day']
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not accounting for your time zone.  The 'time series data' section of the [API docs](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) goes into more detail, but the basic idea is that you'll need to add/subtract your timezone offset from each timestamp.